# How are .Po files created in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, automake

I have changed Makefile of a project and now when I make it, it returns:-

`ERROR: "make[2]: *** No rule to make target ../libvmi/driver/.deps/xen.Po.  Stop. "`

How does Makefile create `.Po` files and how can I disable creating it for a certain file like  `../libvmi/driver/.deps/xen.c`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.Po` files are used as part of automake's dependency tracking. They are usually created by `config.status` as empty files, which get overwritten by actual dependencies when the compiler is invoked. (automake's approach is to do dependency generation as a side-effect of compilation.)

I've found that running `make -k` (`-k` is short for `--keep-going`) will be enough to unstick the build, once the file whose .Po is missing has been recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

Automake uses dependencies for compilation by default. Dependencies are created in the .deps/ folder with the extension .Po.

Dependencies can be disabled. For various methods on turning dependencies off, see https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Dependencies.html

In my Makefile.am, I added the no-dependencies flag which prevents the .deps/ folder and .Po files from being created.

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects no-dependencies
```